# summarise to multiple columns using tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with two columns.

Col A is a vector of references, and Col B is the corresponding vector of study sites in the reference.

My problem is that in one reference there could be multiple study sites, and one study site maybe found in multiple references too.

I want to make a summary of study sites, returning as many columns as there are that are linked to the study site.

Something like:

```
Original table
-------------
ref  | site
-------------
A    | S1
-------------
A    | S2
-------------
B    | S1
-------------

New table
site  | ref1 | ref2
-------------------
S1    | A    | B
-------------------
S2    | A    | NA
-------------------
```

`spread` doesn't work since there are duplicates of `site`.

Comment: `spread` will work if you do `df %>% spread(key=ref,value=ref)`.  An alternative would be to use `table(df$site,df$ref)`

Comment: This doesn't work. `ref` is non-unique and can't be `key`.

Comment: It worked for me on your data above and `tidyr 0.8.0`

Comment: That's because my actual data have lots more duplicates than this simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get `spread` to work and generate the columns you want as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)
original <- tibble(
  ref = c("A", "A", "B", "A"),
  site = c("S1", "S2", "S1", "S1")
)

original %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  mutate(refcount = str_c("ref", row_number())) %>%
  spread(refcount, ref)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   site [2]
#>   site  ref1  ref2 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 S1    A     B    
#> 2 S2    A     <NA>
```

Created on 2018-06-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This spreads all the references. I only want to keep the unique ones for each site.

Comment: add a call to `distinct()` in that case. answer updated

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!